# how to display recall data from database PHP

Tags: php, sql, forms, datatable

I really need everyone helps. I've been creating a simple system, but then there's a problem occur when im trying too display data from database into table form. I try to fix it but i cant seem to find the errors anywhere. Below is my php codes. Can anyone tell me whats wrong with it cause i cant get the data to be display but there is no error instead the page echo "no data found" when there is lots of data. Thanks everyone.

```
 <?php
include 'config.php';
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['username'];

$query="SELECT * FROM form WHERE requester='$user'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result2) == 0){ 
echo("no data found"); 
} ELSE {

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.'Date'.'</td><td>'.'Requester'.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.'Status'.'</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>'.$row['date'].'</td><td>'.$row['requester'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['status'].'</td></tr>';}}

?>
```

Comment: Your query returns its result to `$result` but you check the number of rows in `$result2`. Note that `mysql_*()` is deprecated. You shouldn't use it for new code.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your comment. I'll change it already but still it doesn't shows the data , what should i do ?

Comment: @zara, one way to check is to `echo $user;` when you run the code and then make sure that there are actually results where the requester column matches the value of `$user`. It should work when you change `mysql_num_rows($result2)` to `mysql_num_rows($result)`...

Comment: @MxmastaMills thank you for your comment :) i have try as your suggestion and it echo $user. However it still didnt display the data. I figure it have something to do with table form cause when i try other table, it work just fine.

Comment: @zara, you could try to query the database with an explicit value/string of something that you know definitely exists instead of the variable $user as well to see if it's the info in the database that's the problem or it's the syntax of the code.